# Why Angular website (irctc.co.in) require to put Script WaitForAngularEnabled false.? without this code is not worked

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

```
describe('Protractor Alert steps', function () {
   it('Open Angular js website Alerts', function () {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get("https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search");
        element(by.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Ok')]")).click();
      })
})
```

Now it is worked with above code but can u explain me

This is angular website then  why below statement is  required to be false

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); ?
```

Without above line code is not worked ...

Comment: error stack would help to understand better what's happening. But I can guess you don't handle promises with `await` key word

Answer (score 0):

This is an error below The promise do not require to handel -

[31mF[0mA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

Failures:
1) Protractor Alert steps Open Angular js website Alerts
  Message:
[31m    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.[0m
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
        at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
  Message:
[31m    Failed: script timeout

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a timeout error. Modify your timeout limits in your Configuration file.

```js
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 90 * 1000, // Set to 90 seconds
    getPageTimeout: 15 * 1000, // Set to 15 seconds

    // if you're using Node, you might want to adjust this as well:
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60 * 1000, // 60 second timeout
        print: function() {}
    },
};
```

Just a word of caution: long tests are fragile tests. Adjust your timeouts carefully.